# Up/Down voting breakdown on questions and answers

Tags: support

I was recently invited to the new Embedded Systems beta and I noticed that I could click on the vote number of a question or answer and it would show me the breakdown of up votes versus down votes.  I thought this was pretty cool and mentioned to a friend that I wished the EE.SE could do that too... To which he replied that it did.

So, I guess my question is: **What is the rule/pattern for being able to view the up/down vote breakdown for a question or answer?**

It doesn't seem to simply be rep based because I have 101 rep on Embedded Systems and *I can* see the breakdown... but I have 560 rep on Electrical Engineering and *cannot* see it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On EE.SE, the the Up/Down breakdown privilege turns on at [1k reputation (established user)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user).

I'm guessing that privileges in the stacks that are in beta (like Embedded Systems) turn on at lower reputation, because their number of members is smaller.

Comment: Interesting... I would not have expected it to be different on different exchanges.

Comment: The thresholds shift once a site leaves the beta period.

Comment: Why is access to this limited?

Comment: @AdamHead, this is quite an old anser but the reason from Jeff Atwood (original co-founder of SE) was to limit its usage for performance reasons: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes

Comment: @AdamHead - Thresholds change for: Private beta -> Public Beta -> Graduation